# How to send in postman Map with key as object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, postman

I have such an entity structure so I want to send a post request and create Order with all properties.
How to request body should look like in postman?

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id int id;

    String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="INVENTORY", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STORE"))
    @Column(name="COPIES_IN_STOCK")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="MOVIE", referencedColumnName="ID")
    Map<Item, Integer> items;
 
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id long id;
    String name;

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/order")
public class OrderController {

    public final OrderService orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }
    @PostMapping
    public void saveOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
         orderService.save(order);
    }
}
```

---

this is the wrong body, so I try to find out how it should look according to my data model

```
{
     "name":"first order",
     "items": {
         "item-1":{
              "name": "frist item"  
         },
         "item-2":{
             "name": "second item"  
         }
     }
}
```

expect to get the status to receive from the client Order with the whole structure

example from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html)
data what I got [screenshot](https://ibb.co/0nt52MP)

Comment: To get an answer for how to send this request in postman, you will need to include the Controller method declaration so we can see what RequestBody you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@RequestBody` by default cannot handle this example request:

```json
{
     "name":"first order",
     "items": {
         "item-1":{
              "name": "frist item"  
         },
         "item-2":{
             "name": "second item"  
         }
     }
}
```

For that you should try something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id int id;

    String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="INVENTORY", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STORE"))
    @Column(name="COPIES_IN_STOCK")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="MOVIE", referencedColumnName="ID")
    Map<Item, Integer> items;
 
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addItems(String key, Item item) {
        items.put(item, Integer.valueOf(key.split("-")));
    }
    
}
```

If you want to count the item's repetition number as a key in the hashmap put your logic in this setter

Comment: I think I shouldn't adjust my data model to request a body conversely I wanna adjust the request body according to such data model [Example 2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html)
if it works with List<Object> it have to works with Map<Object, Object>